# Mirror playing video as background without double buffering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

My website shows a video, that's sort of the main thing it does. I wonder, can I use the very same video, preferrably without loading it twice and use it as a background (perhaps with a blurred effect) on the rest of the site?

```
_________________
|    <html>     |
|     _____     |
|    <video>    |
|    </video>   |
|               |
| Same <video>  |
| as background |
|               |
|    </html>    |
|_______________|
```

I know this is ridiculously poorly explained, but I don't know where to start. I figured jQuery sounded like an appropriate tag, but I'm not even sure about that. I know one would normally link what they've tried, but I don't know where to start. As I said, I'd very much prefer not having to buffer it twice, which in my world means not adding another `<video>` element, but using some sort of js to reflect it somehow. A plugin, perhaps?

Any sort of guidance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `timeupdate` event of `video` to draw image of `video` to `canvas` element using `drawImage()`; use `css` `vw`, `vh` values to set `canvas` to cover viewport, set `position` to `absolute` at both `video` and `canvas` elements, `filter` property with `blur()` value to set blur effect of `canvas`, set `z-Index` of `canvas` to value less than `z-Index` of `video` element.

```css
body {
  width: 94vw;
  height: 100vw;
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  z-Index: 1;
  left: 25vw;
}
canvas {
  width: 94vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  z-Index: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <video width="300px" height="200px;" src="http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm" autoplay loop></video>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var video = document.querySelector("video");
      var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(event) {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: better using a requestAnimationFrame to draw your video on canvas if you're not doing any processing on the canvas data, and remember to resize your canvas' `width`and `height` properties to the video's `videoWidth`and `videoHeight` properties' values.

Comment: @Kaiido Was not certain if a delayed effect was expected or as close to original as possible. The delayed effect provided by the periodic `timeupdate` event was used at post. The `css` was, or could be,  more involved that the `javascript` portions. _"and remember to resize your canvas' `width` and `height` properties to the video's `videoWidthand` `videoHeight` properties' values"_ Believe OP is trying to fill entire viewport with with `canvas`, or other approach, as a background _"use it as a background (perhaps with a blurred effect) on the rest of the site?"_ and play video in foreground.

Comment: @Kaiido Note, `left:25vw` at `video` was used to place `video` at center of stacksnippets viewport; may require further adjustment

Comment: yes but even if you do scale it with css, you have to resize the canvas in order to draw the full video on your canvas, here you are only drawing a 300*250 crop of the original video

Comment: @Kaiido If interpret your last comment correctly, yes, to fit in stacksnippets window. Adjustments could be made to `width`, `height` of either element to achieve exacting results, depending on expected effect. Though, perhaps am not gathering what you are attempting to convey?

Comment: well just look at how your blurred version is actually cropped : its default size is 300*150 px, this means you can only draw on this 300*150 px. You are drawing a 455*IDKpx at coordinate 0,0 without using the scaling properties of drawImage which means that you'll only have the top left corner of the video. **resizing a canvas with CSS doesn't change it's number of drawable pixels**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113364/discussion-between-guest271314-and-kaiido).

Comment: And unfortuantely, CSS effects seems to render really slow, in future (or by enabling some prefrences in your browser), we'll be able to use directly `ctx.blur(length)`, but for now, parsing the imagedata, or using some drawImage tricks might have a better result...

Comment: @Kaiido What do you mean by _"CSS effects seems to render really slow"_?

Comment: on my computer, even using rAF, css filter causes a lot of lags in canvas rendering, using canvas filter is way more smooth. But as I said it's not widely supported yet. There is [this library](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) which allows to blur anything on canvas though.

Comment: @Kaiido Utilizing `videoHeight` and `videoWidth` made a substantial difference http://embed.plnkr.co/5I16MrzY6PUmhPe99zZN/